# Cruise Control Installation error

Tags: java, cruisecontrol

I am trying to install Cruise Control on my Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise.
While installing , I got java version compatibility errors and found a solution for the same at stackoverflow: [Cruise Control service error: Cannot construct net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.BuildLoopInformation as it does not have a no-args constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169454/cruise-control-service-error-cannot-construct-net-sourceforge-cruisecontrol-bui/20699425#20699425)

Now, I ran into a different installation problem (attached the screenshot):

Please help... Thank you :)

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.BuildLoopInformation cannot be cast to net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.BuildLoopInformation
  at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.util.BuildInformationHelper.toObject(BuildInformationHelper.java:32)
  at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.dashboard.web.BuildLoopController.handleRequestInternal(BuildLoopController.java:28)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:858)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:792)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:441)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
  at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
  at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

Comment: I am sorry, unable to attach the screenshot as I do not have enough points.

Comment: So did you end up using Java 6 or 7? The post you quoted suggested a few solutions.

Comment: Hi Isim,  my java version is : 
C:\Users\pi7adm>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_20

Answer (score 0):

I just tested a new installation on my Windows box with Java 1.8.0_25, using the binary distribution of CC 2.8.4. It seems to work just fine out-of-the-box.

Here are my steps:

1. Download CruiseControl 2.8.4 binary distribution: [cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cruisecontrol/files/CruiseControl/2.8.4/)
2. Unzip it to my `C:` drive.
3. Execute `cruisecontrol.bat` from command prompt.
4. Navigate to dashboard located at your `http://localhost:8080/dashboard/tab/dashboard`

Give them a try and see if they work.

Honestly though, I think you should consider using [Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/888054/1144203).

Comment: Hi Isim,
I have followed the same steps as you mentioned.
However, I am getting the same error again.
I have used Teamcity and Jenkins also. But, for this project I need cruise control.

Comment: Which error? `...Cannot construct net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.BuildLoopInformation as it does not have a no-args constructor` or `...java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.BuildLoopInformation cannot be cast to...`?